# module.map for accessing (Swift and Objective-C) classes in main target from test target

Tags: objective-c, swift, module, xcode6, xctest

I am in the process of adding Swift classes to an existing Objective-C project. As part of this, I have added a `MyProjectTests.swift` to the target `MyProjectTests`. It imports Swift classes from target `MyProject` with `import MyProject` and that works just fine.

I now want to use `@import Swift;` in `MyProjectTests.m`as well. However, the compiler issues the error `Module 'MyProject' not found`.

I have these questions:

**Make both import and @import succeed in test target**

Why can it be the case that the Swift compiler sees module `MyProject` but the Objective-C compiler does not? What build settings in `MyProjectTest` do I have to change to make `@import MyProject` succeed as well.

**Export Objective-C classes from main target**

Ultimately `MyProjectTest.swift` and `MyProjectTest.m` also need access to Objective-C classes from target `MyProject`. So far I have multi-targetted such files, but I want to switch to using modules also here.

My current understanding is that this is a matter of providing a [`module.map`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) file which would list header files for the classes I wish to "export".

What are the exact steps I have to go through? Where should I place the header file and which build settings do I need to change in the two targets `MyProject` and `MyProjectTests`?

I currently have a (so far empty) `module.map` inside my project and build settings for target `MyProject` include `Defines Module: Yes`, `Product Module Name: MyProject`.

**UPDATE** I am by now wondering whether it might be impossible to expose (Objective-C) files from an iOS application (instead of [framework](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/417)) project as a module. But then it already seems to work for Swift files (somehow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've by now concluded that this is not possible with current Xcode (6.1.1) tooling. (What a waste of time!)

The old scheme of bi-targeting source files to both `MyProject` and `MyProjetTest` also presents several challenges for a mixed Objective-C/Swift project with a non-trivial amount of code:

- Its Objective-C part defines a legacy `NS_ENUM(Integer, Repeat)` which name-clashes with `Swift.Repeat<T>`. Referring to it as `MyProject.Repeat` (not `MyProjectTests.Repeat`) causes problems when compiling for target `MyProjectTests`, which changing this target's `Project Name` (also) to `MyProject` (not: `MyProjectTests`) does not seem to solve.
- Compilation of constructs where Swift class `A` employs Objective-C class `B`, which in turn employs Swift class `C` does not seem to be possible in a straightforward way. Since the compiler has not yet produced `MyProject-Swift.h` with the definition of `C`, it cannot compile `B`. But since it cannot compile `B` it cannot compile `A` and therefore cannot produce `MyProject-Swift.h`. Catch 22, or so it seems.
- Bi-targeted Swift code imports Swift classes from auto-generated `MyProject-Swift.h`. For the target `MyProjectTests` this name does not apply, yet that's what it is in the source files. I did not want to go down the road of changing `MyProjectTests`' `Project Name` (see above). Importing the right auto-generated file via the targets `*.pch` may be possible, but then it may be not ...